# How to tell if a user's java code compiled successfully?

Tags: java, php, compilation, compiler-errors, sandbox

I have a web app running on a LAMP stack that allows users to write java code into an HTML form, but depending on whether or not that code compiles successfully, I want to do different things.

The way I have it currently is that the PHP program would generate a .java file using user's input, execute it on the server (I have the security part taken care of), and then check to see if any errors were output.

I know that Java prints errors out using the System.err stream, is there a way for me to tell if that output anything to the console? Like a way to listen and distinguish output streams of a program?

Comment: Why can't you use whether the .java file is generated after compiling. Note that before compiling delete the old java file generated.

Comment: Oh, that's a very good idea. Never thought of that.

Comment: "use whether the **.class** file is generated after compiling" not ".java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the javac exit code. Here is a list of the javac exit code:

```
static final int
    EXIT_OK = 0,        // Compilation completed with no errors.
    EXIT_ERROR = 1,     // Completed but reported errors.
    EXIT_CMDERR = 2,    // Bad command-line arguments
    EXIT_SYSERR = 3,    // System error or resource exhaustion.
    EXIT_ABNORMAL = 4;  // Compiler terminated abnormally
```

References: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7014715

Since Java 6, you can programmatically call the Java compiler (if provided).
See this: [ToolProvider#getSystemJavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler())

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And PHP when executing the javac command to compile the code can return the exit code.